# Why using this settings i am not getting a proper thesis like font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

```
\documentclass[a412pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\doublespacing

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{split}{\linespread{1}\selectfont}{}{}
\newcommand\etc{{\sl etc\/.}}
\newcommand\formul{formul{\ae}}
```

and using this settings my document has a very large unused portion and it is also not like an usual scientific thesis
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I have no clue what you are currently unsatisfied with. The font? Which unused portion? The margins? Where is the code you are now using coming from? Why are you using it?

Comment: What is a usual scientific thesis? Requirements change from town to town and university to university all over the world.

Comment: I am using this settings in my course work thesis writing and compareing it with the regular doctral thesises and it is different

Answer (score 1):

Use package geometry and set the margins as you like.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lmargin=..., rmargin=...,bmargin=...,tmargin=...]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks Red-Cloud